# ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure with WSL2

Tags: python, cx-oracle, wsl-2

I'm trying to connect to an oracle database via the cx_Oracle python library but am getting the error message "ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure".

My connection logic currently looks like this:

```
import cx_Oracle as cOr
cOr.connect("USER_NAME/USER_PASSWORD@HOST_NAME:PORT/SERVICE_NAME")
```

My program is running on the WSL2 environment on a windows10 machine, so somehow I think this is where the trouble originates from. The python version I'm using is 3.6.9, cx-Oracle is 8.2.1 and this instant client necessary for the cx-Oracle is in version 21_1.

I found for example this article here https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7018259 on this topic. Yet all the checks they mention there succeed for me, so it shouldn't be, that the target is simply not reachable from my system.

Also just using the Oracle SQL developer from the Windows part of the machine with the same data is working just fine.

I'm a bit out of ideas of what to do on this topic and hope for somebody to maybe give me a good hint. If there is any additional information you need from me I'll gladly provide it.

Comment: Try using SQL*Plus, which uses the same Oracle "client" libraries that cx_Oracle does.  SQL Developer is a different stack.  (Overall, it would be best to use a supported OS!)